# How to get object type/identifier?

Tags: powershell, properties, active-directory

In PowerShell, when I work with Active Directory specifically, often I'll compile an object containing a list of groups of people usually with `$x = get-adgroup -filter {name -like "*"} | select-object name` which gives me a list with a header or object type name:

```
   name   
----------
  name1
  name2
  name3
```

How can I access the name header of the object or even change it to something else?
Can it be done similarly to the way I would access the string of the first entry like `$x[0].name`?
Further, is there a more generic way to access the string associated with an arbitrary entry?

I'm being asked to a lot of "programming" in PowerShell related to AD so any resources you can provide to help me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things that I think you are asking for is a programmatic way to determine the name of a given property in an object.

```
(get-aduser $user | select name).psobject.properties


MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : Matt
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : name
IsInstance      : True
```

The `Name` property of `.psobject.properties` contains most of this information and I think you might be looking for.

Was going to answer the second part with what Arco444 just said about using `select-object`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the name you can create an expression for it in your select block:

```
get-adgroup -filter {name -like "*"} | select-object @{Name="WhatYouWannaCallIt";Expression={$_.Name}}
```

This would now give you:

```
WhatYouWannaCallIt   
------------------
     name1
     name2
     name3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$x = get-adgroup -filter {name -like "*"}
$x.name
```

or

```
(get-adgroup -filter {name -like "*"}).name
```