# How to run if inline on PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have this function;

```
Function SomeCommand{
    param(
        [string]$Var1,
        [string]$Var2
    )

    # Do Something
}
```

I could set it up like this;

```
Function SomeCommand{
    param(
        [string]$Var1,
        [string]$Var2
    )

    if ($Var2){
        Do-SomeOtherCommand -SomeParam1 $Var1 -SomeParam2 $Var2
    } else {
        Do-SomeOtherCommand -SomeParam1 $Var1
}
```

This works fine if I only have one optional parameter, but if I have two it gets harry. I would like to do something like this;

```
Function SomeCommand{
    param(
        [string]$Var1,
        [string]$Var2,
        [string]$Var3
    )

    Do-SomeOtherCommand -SomeParam1 $Var1 (if($Var2){-SomeParam2 $Var2}) (if($Var3){-SomeParam3 $Var3})
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would highly recommend this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551258/powershell-how-to-get-object-type-identifier/27551513#27551513. Looks to be up your alley. Basically you should use [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) by building a hashtable of the properties you want

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood, but splatting appears to be the ability to assume parameters based off their position. There does seem to be a subsection on @Args that might be applicable but I'd have to get smarter on it.

Comment: Just wanted to give kudos, you were right; I should have been able to understand the example at technet. Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping you would see my question more than the technet. I'm glad you found the answer regardless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx).  You can build up a hashtable with the parameters you wish to pass (and their values), then specify the whole thing in one shot:

```
function FuncB($param1, $param2)
{
   "FuncB -- param1:[$param1] param2:[$param2]"
}

function FuncA($paramA, $paramB)
{
   $args = @{}
   if ($paramA){ $args['param1'] = $paramA }
   if ($paramB){ $args['param2'] = $paramB }

   FuncB @args
}
```

Test

```
FuncA 'first' 'second'
FuncA 'OnlyFirst'
FuncA -paramB 'OnlySecond'

# results
# FuncB -- param1:[first] param2:[second]
# FuncB -- param1:[OnlyFirst] param2:[]
# FuncB -- param1:[] param2:[OnlySecond]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for stepping it out for me! I would upvote you but I need 15 rep. I'll come back and do it when I have the rep!

Comment: There is an automatic variable called `$PSBoundParameters` could be used in this way `FuncB @PSBoundParameters` if all the parameter names match on the two functions.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go for these kinds of things. @kevmar note that `$PSBoundParameters` only contains parameters that are *specified* (bound) by the caller. If you have an optional parameter with a default value, its value will not be included. I wrote a [blog post about this](http://www.briantist.com/how-to/splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters/) actually. :)

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons.  PowerShell allows you to use semicolons as line terminators.

```
Write-Output 1;Write-Output 2;Write-Output 3;
```

Personally, I think it should be mandatory.

Comment: This would be the same as a carriage return. I want to modify the current command using 'if' inline.

    Write-Host "my message" + if(foo){"more message"}

Comment: Oh.  Subexpression then.  `Write-Host "my message" + $(if(foo){"more message"})`

Comment: Ok, so in relation to my question, adding the $ for the subexpression Do-SomeOtherCommand -SomeParam1 $Var1 $(if($Var2){-SomeParam2 $Var2}) $(if($Var3){-SomeParam3 $Var3}) still doesn't seem to work. EDIT: How did you do the code annotation in your reply?

Comment: Backticks (\`) around code will format it as code.  However, @Matt is right.  You probably should be using splatting.  Sorry, I was confused about what you were asking originally and in a hurry, which doesn't mix.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you can build up an arbitrary expression as a simple string, then use [Invoke-Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) (alias `iex`) to invoke it inline.

```
function FuncB($param1, $param2)
{
   "FuncB -- param1:[$param1] param2:[$param2]"
}

function FuncA($paramA, $paramB)
{
  $funcBCall = "FuncB $(if($paramA){ "-param1 '$paramA'" }) $(if($paramB){ "-param2 '$paramB'" })"
  iex $funcBCall
}
```

This approach is very hacky and brittle, though, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question exactly. The only reason that I was asking for an inline solution was because I had more than one conditional. Thanks again!